# MySQL select with condition on left join table returns incomplete result set

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database containing two tables: event and session (one event has multiple sessions).

I am building a query where I want to list event names and their corresponding first session date and last session date so users can see a range.

The issue is if the session table doesn't have any records for the event the event is not included in the result set (range_start and range_finish should be NULL).

How can I fix my query to include all records from the event table even if it doesn't have any sessions?

```
SELECT e.id, e.name, MIN(s.date_start) AS range_start, MAX(s.date_finish) AS range_finish
FROM `event` AS e
LEFT JOIN `session` AS s
ON e.id = s.event_id 
WHERE s.hidden != 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT e.id, e.name, MIN(s.date_start) AS range_start, MAX(s.date_finish) AS range_finish
FROM `event` AS e
LEFT JOIN `session` AS s
ON e.id = s.event_id 
WHERE (s.hidden != 1)
OR s.hidden IS NULL
```

Assuming s.hidden cannot naturally be null.

Comment: Only refinement I made was to add GROUP BY e.id at the end. Thanks